# Unable to shutdown, restart or logout

Tags: boot, grub2, shutdown, brightness, logout

I am unable to shutdown, restart or logout from my ubuntu 14.04 machine.
The screen goes blank, but the system hangs, then the fan begins to run fast.
I have to turnoff the laptop by pressing and holding the power key. Sometimes this happens during booting also.
As a solution I updated the grub which didn't work.
I am using an Acer Aspire E5 laptop[E5-511-P75Y] with UEFI booting.
Windows works fine on this laptop.
I have the same problem using the terminal: `sudo shutdown -P now`.
The grub file content is:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force apm=power_off"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

To find the point where the system hangs i updated the grub:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nosplash acpi=force apm=power_off"
```

and I found the following messege when the system hangs:

```
dw_dmac INTL9c68:00 Invalid resource
```

Please note that this happens only sometimes during booting, but always during shutdown or logout.

Comment: I think you need more RAM. I have 4 GB of RAM +8 GB SWAP on a  14.10. and then it works without any hangup. But when load increases it dies and need forced reboot or a pause of 10-20 mins. OR  In your case, if possible, try reinstalling ubuntu or upgrade to latest version. I assume something that has crashed. (You can increase SWAP space if you're reinstalling it.)

Comment: @trex I don't think missing RAM/swap is the problem. I used to run 14.10 with no swap and 2GB RAM for a while without problems... But Akhil Palakkad, please add some system specs (like CPU, RAM,...) to eliminate this possible cause.

Comment: and `iostat`... and `free --human` (before/while shutting down)

Comment: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=101271

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in your video card try

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx xvba-va-driver libva-glx1 libva-egl1 vainfo
```

EDIT: 
    Try:

```
sudo apt-get install libcheese*
sudo apt-get install xorg-video-abi-15
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates
```

Comment: I tried  I got the following result: '
                  xorg-video-abi-14 but it is not installable or
                  xorg-video-abi-15
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.'

Comment: I've edited my answer

Comment: I tried. It didn't work either. I am editing the question.

Comment: Booting stops with the messege:`dw_dmac INTL9c68:00 Invalid resource`.

Answer (score -2):

A solution no free, but i worked, is select the system configuration->Software and Updates-> additional controllers and select the controller privative